# Another Way to Conclude an Answer

Tags: answers

I understand that `\boxed{}` would give a box surrounding a math. However, I want to make answer this way instead of full rectangular box.

Is there a way to make this command to, say, `\halfboxed{x=3}`?

Thanks,
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might like `tcbhighmath` from the `tcolorbox` package:

[image]

Here's a complete MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} 

\begin{document}

\[
\tcbhighmath[frame hidden,colback=white,enhanced,overlay unbroken={%
\draw[thick,red,double] (interior.north east)--(interior.south east)--(interior.south west);
},]{x=3}
\]

\end{document}
```

Of course, you'd probably prefer to use something like:

```
\tcbset{Panha/.style={frame hidden,colback=white,enhanced,overlay unbroken={%
\draw[thick,red,double] (interior.north east)--(interior.south east)--(interior.south west);}}}
```

in your preamble, so that you can simply use `\tcbhighmath[Panha]{x=3}` in the document, for example:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} 

\tcbset{Panha/.style={frame hidden,colback=white,enhanced,overlay unbroken={%
\draw[thick,red,double] (interior.north east)--(interior.south east)--(interior.south west);}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\tcbhighmath[Panha]{x=3}
\]

\end{document}
```